# JSOUP Unresolved compilation: ignoreHttpErrors() is undefined for the type Connection

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm getting this error when calling [ignoreHttpErrors(boolean)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#ignoreHttpErrors%28boolean%29) using [JSoup 1.6.3](http://jsoup.org/)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The method ignoreHttpErrors(boolean) is undefined for the
>   type Connection

Is it a referencing problem with my setup? 
Any idea how to fix it?

Eclipse validates the code with no errors and 1 warning.

The following code won't compile.

```
try {

            Connection.Response response =   Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5")
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .followRedirects(false)
                    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)  // <--- Underlined red in eclipse plus the error msg
                    .execute();

            int statusCode = response.statusCode();
            System.out.println("received status code : " + statusCode);
            if(statusCode == 200) {
                System.out.println("Found : " + statusCode);                    
            }
            else if(statusCode == 404){
                System.out.println("Not Found : " + statusCode);                    
            }
            else if(statusCode == 302){
                System.out.println("Page Moved : " + statusCode);                   
            }

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Timeout occured");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O problem");
        }
```

**EDIT 1**

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

System.out.println(Connection.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
System.out.println(Document.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

**Output**

```
file:/C:/opt/glassfish/glassfish/modules/bean-validator.jar
file:/C:/opt/glassfish/glassfish/modules/bean-validator.jar
```

Hmmm, not what I was expecting at all. I have jsoup-1.6.3.jar in the Library Directory of my EAR. The calling code is in an EJB packaged within the EAR.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ignoreHttpErrors()` method is new since [1.6.0](http://jsoup.org/news/release-1.6.0). Apparently you've still an older version of Jsoup somewhere in the classpath which got precedence in classloading.

To nail down its exact location in the classpath, execute the following

```
System.out.println(Connection.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

Where `Connection` is obviously the Jsoup one. It should then be a matter of removing the duplicate older versioned JAR file at the given location.

Comment: Oh, you're running this in a Java EE webapp? I didn't expect that at all, I expected a plain Java application with `main()` method or so as you were using `System.out.println()` over all place... Anyway, just search for `jsoup*.jar` files in all paths covered by the classpath of the Java EE webapp :) You can get all those paths by `ClassLoader#getResources()` passing an empty string where `ClassLoader` is the one as obtained from the current thread context.

Comment: Yeah I was just doing some basic PoC testing. Thanks for the help regards the classpath issue, I'll have to come back to this later.